# Is there a way to set a breakpoint so I can see what happens during RenderTransform?

Tags: c#, wpf

So when I need to see what is being passed into layout, I just override measure and arrange in some controls and set breakpoints so I can see the layout process.

is there anything similar I could use to try to understand what is happening during the application of transforms? I have a strange bug that occurs on resize of a canvas containing visuals. The canvas has a translate transform and scaletransform applied to it, but the placement of visuals seems to shift on resize.

Comment: None I am aware of. But to your other problem - the order of your transforms is essetial! Most "bugs" cause by transforms are caused by applying in wrong order. You should never scale without you moving your object to origin first unless you want different effect(moving the object as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx

I have VS2012 Express, where option ***Enable .NET Framework*** in *Debug\Options and Settings\Debugging\General* does not exist, that`s why I can not tell exactly how breakpoints in XAML work.